# pg_hba error while setting up repmgr

Tags: postgresql, pg-hba.conf, repmgr

Please help me to figure it out, help is much appreciated!

ERROR:

```
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "172.18.0.4", user "repmgr", SSL on
```

The following is a list of my pg_hba entries:[image]

The following is the query output from pg_hba_file_rules:

```
line_number | type  |   database    | user_name  |  address   |                 netmask                 | auth_method | options | error
------------+-------+---------------+------------+------------+-----------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------
      85 | local | {all}         | {postgres} |            |                                         | peer        |         |
      90 | local | {all}         | {all}      |            |                                         | peer        |         |
      92 | host  | {all}         | {all}      | 127.0.0.1  | 255.255.255.255                         | md5         |         |
      94 | host  | {all}         | {all}      | ::1        | ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff | md5         |         |
      97 | local | {replication} | {all}      |            |                                         | peer        |         |
      98 | host  | {replication} | {all}      | 127.0.0.1  | 255.255.255.255                         | md5         |         |
      99 | host  | {replication} | {all}      | ::1        | ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff | md5         |         |
     101 | host  | {all}         | {repmgr}   | 172.18.0.0 | 255.255.255.0                           | trust       |         |
     102 | host  | {replication} | {repmgr}   | 172.18.0.0 | 255.255.255.0                           | trust       |         |
```

As you can see, the pg_hba.conf did get loaded to the database. 
Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Finally got it working!!!

> Since the pg_hba.conf records are examined sequentially for each connection attempt, the order of the records is significant. Typically, earlier records will have tight connection match parameters and weaker authentication methods, while later records will have looser match parameters and stronger authentication methods.

Comment: But what earlier one was it matching?  And if it was matching an earlier one, why would it say there was no entry found?  I often see this when the first attempt was with SSL on, it failed (for example, wrong password) so automatically retires with SSL off and fails with no hba entry.  Only the last failure is reported.  But that doesn't really explain your situation.

Comment: but how did you get it working....